# How to get this random

Tags: javascript

```
var mess = [];
mess.push('test1');
mess.push('test2');
mess.push('test3');
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * mess.length));
document.writeln(mess[num]);
```

This code here generates a random output when refreshing the page. What I want to know how to do is get it to change automatically like dynamically on the page it will change every 5 seconds or so.

How would I go about doing this?

Any help is appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a container in your HTML, instead of using `document.writeln`:

```
<span id="target">This will be filled by Javascript</span>
```

Now wrap your code in a function, store its result in the `span`, and use `setTimeout` to make it periodical.

```
var mess = [];
mess.push('test1');
mess.push('test2');
mess.push('test3');

function randomize() {
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = 
             mess[Math.floor((Math.random() * mess.length))];
    setTimeout(randomize, 5000);
}
randomize(); // initial call to get it going
```

Put the Javascript in your code *after* the declaration of the span, or you'll get an error stating that you `Cannot set property innerHTML on NULL`.

Comment: Make sure however that the initial call is onDOMready or at least in a script placed after the `#target`

Comment: @Bergi I think I was adding that last line simultaneously with your comment - but yeah that's important of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function.

Sorry if I missunderstood your question, but you want something like this right?

```
window.onload = function(){
    var mess = [];
    mess.push('test1');
    mess.push('test2');
    mess.push('test3');

    (function r() {
       var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * mess.length));
       document.body.innerHTML = mess[num];
       setTimeout(r, 5000);
    })();

};
```

Comment: This is obviously not going to work, `document.writeln` can only be called during incremental page load - there is no document to write to after 5 seconds.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I'm assuming that he knows what he's doing, and I've tested and it works normally.

Comment: Ew, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) indeed says the document is implicitly opened. Still that means you're not closing it (causing eternal load) and you're creating wildly invalid HTML by writing outside the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `setInterval` to generate a new random index at interval of every 5 seconds and then print random value from array.

```
var mess = [];
mess.push('test1');
mess.push('test2');
mess.push('test3');

setInterval(
function() {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * mess.length))
    document.write(mess[num]);        
}, 5000);
```

Refer this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3wpcp35L/

Comment: While `setInterval` seems fit for the purpose, I didn't use it in my answer on purpose since it'll keep the value uninitialized for the first 5 seconds. Recursive `setTimeout` is clearer and shorter in that case.